# How to add language prefix in url in Gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to add language prefix in url like localhost/**en**/someurl or localhost/**de**/someurl.
I found this solution:

```golang
en := r.Group("/en")
{
    en.GET("/someurl", ...)
    ...
}
de := r.Group("/de")
{
    de.GET("/someurl", ...)
    ...
}
```

but it requires to repeat all routers and add new language will require another duplication. Can I avoid it with Gin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a [path parameter](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#parameters-in-path) instead?

```golang
r.Get("/:lang/someurl", ...)
```

In the handler you can then access the language:

```golang
func(c *gin.Context) {
    lang := c.Param("lang")

    // ...
}
```